# Json объекты в PHP

Tags: php, массивы, json

У менять есть такой json:

```
[{"id":"01","count":"446","color":"#EB6182"}]
```

Как мне переменной вывести только count?

```
$json = json_decode($data);
print_r($json->count[0]);
```

Не помогает почему то

Comment: $json[0]->count; вот это заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Php sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/24ac6b804f9df20fda627c8141e71c734fc5adde)

Код

```
<?php

$data = '[{"id":"01","count":"446","color":"#EB6182"}]';

$decodedObject = json_decode($data);
print_r($decodedObject[0]->count);

$decodedArray = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($decodedArray[0]['count']);
```

У вас перед JSON объектом стоит **[** и в конце **]**
Это массив, соответственно перед тем как получить сам объект, необходимо указать **[0]** как первый элемент массива и уже дальше работать как нужно.